# How to understand the word order in this sentence?

Tags: word-order

"Wenn du lächelst, lächelt die Welt auch zurück."

Why is the verb not in the second position in this sentence? Instead, we have "du" in the second position. And why is "lächelt" the first word in the phrase "lächelt die Welt auch zurück."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a subordinate clause, the verb is in the last position.

> Ich freue mich, *wenn* du **lächelst**. (Note that *freue* follows the V2-scheme)

Adopting these patterns for your example results in something like the following:

> Die Welt *lächelt* auch zurück, *wenn* du **lächelst**.

"*Lächelt*" is in the position you expected.
When a subordinate clause precedes the main clause, the finite verb form comes first in the main clause (unfortunately not always, but usually):

> *Wenn* du **lächelst**, *lächelt* die Welt auch zurück.

---

Some more examples:

> *Weil* ihr **rennt**, *müsst* ihr mit der Schere  *aufpassen*.

> *Wenn* du **losgehst**, *ruf* bitte *an*.

> *Weil* du **lächelst**, *macht* er sich Hoffnungen.

Comment: Perhaps it's more useful to say that the subordinate clause occupies the first position of the main clause in these examples. This way the rule that the finite verb comes on the second position still holds.

Comment: German is called a V2 language, but it really depends on sentence or clause type. Declarative statements, open questions and independent clauses are V2, imperatives, closed questions are V1, subordinate clauses are VL, and there are cases where there is no finite verb at all, which I call V0.